# Javascript RegEx return different result for users

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex condition:

```
if(!/^[a-zA-ZáéőúűóüöíÁŰÚŐÉÓÜÖÍ -]+$/.test(document.getElementById("city").value)){
  return false;
}
```

It returns true for Budapest for some users but for others it returns false. Why is it possible to return different results? Can it depend on browsers versions?

Comment: Probably something related to encoding. You may replace the literal `áéőúűóüöíÁŰÚŐÉÓÜÖÍ` with the `\u00E1\u00E9\u0151\u00FA\u0171\u00F3\u00FC\u00F6\u00ED\u00C1\u0170\u00DA\u0150\u00C9\u00D3\u00DC\u00D6\u00CD` string.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-ZáéőúűóüöíÁŰÚŐÉÓÜÖÍ -]+$/.test("Budapešť")` is false

Comment: Did you log what the actual string is for the ones that fail?

Comment: @mplungjan: it's okay that it's false. I only want to accept Budapest. But sometimes it returns true then for others it returns false. That is what bothers me.

Comment: maybe document.getElementById("city") doesn't have the city the moment you are checking it, but gets it later?

Comment: @AlexG no, document.getElementById('city') is there. It is loaded with the body (but hidden) and show up on a button click and then validated on another click.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i try your recommendation and get back.

Comment: It seems that @WiktorStribiżew solution has solved the problem. Can you add it as an answer?

Comment: @AttilaBorbás Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue usually appears when the encoding differs across systems.

You may replace the literal `áéőúűóüöíÁŰÚŐÉÓÜÖÍ` with the `\u00E1\u00E9\u0151\u00FA\u0171\u00F3\u00FC\u00F6\u00ED\u00C1\u0170\u00DA\u0150\u00C9\u00D3\u00DC\u00D6\u00CD` Unicode code unit sequences, they will get parsed correctly regardless of what encoding is used since they consist of ASCII chars.